# How can I solve ImportError: (unknown location)

Tags: python, module, path, location, importerror

**My proyect tree**

```
.
├── exceptions
│   └── IvalidCreditCardException.py
├── main.py
└── validators
    ├── CreditCardValidatorBase.py
    └── LuhnAlgorithmValidator.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juanjo/Documentos/Sublime-workspace/CreditCardValidator/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from validators import LuhnAlgorithmValidator
  File "/home/juanjo/Documentos/Sublime-workspace/CreditCardValidator/validators/LuhnAlgorithmValidator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from validators import CreditCardValidatorBase
  File "/home/juanjo/Documentos/Sublime-workspace/CreditCardValidator/validators/CreditCardValidatorBase.py", line 3, in <module>
    from exceptions import  InvalidCreditCardException
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidCreditCardException' from 'exceptions' (unknown location)
```

**Lines of code causing the stacktrace**

CreditCardValidatorBase:

> from exceptions import  InvalidCreditCardException

LuhnAlgorithmValidator:

> import CreditCardValidatorBase

Any way of letting python know what the correct path is?.

Comment: try this `from ..exceptions import InvalidCreditCardException` , and then run your `main.py` .If you try to run the `CreditCardValidatorBase.py` only, it will again give you the same importError

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, I just had to add a dot to files in the same dir.

Example:

**LuhnAlgorithmValidator:**

> from .CreditCardValidatorBase import CreditCardValidatorBase